# I am not able to SFTP files from Aix server to Windows server through application

Tags: java, unix, encryption, sftp, aix

I am not able to SFTP files from Aix server to Windows server through application.

```
com.maverick.ssh.SshException: Failed to negotiate a transport component [aes192-cbc] [aes256-ctr] [Unknown cause]
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.B(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.C(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.startTransportProtocol(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.Ssh2Client.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. On which system do you run your program? Does the program work with other servers? Show a [mre].

Comment: One of the two sides uses a really old ssh-implementation.

Comment: What version of J2SSH Maverick are you using? And why does it only have one cipher configured? Even many older versions support more ciphers than what is listed in the error. Provide more context and code snippets to demonstrate how you are using and configuring the API you are using in your application.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/disabling-cipher-block-chaining-cbc-mode-ciphers-and-weak-mac-algorithms-ssh-ibm-puredata-system-operational-analytics please visit this and disable the CBC cipher from your source server.